# boundedness of signed measure $\mu$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$ for all $A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In my text, the claim is made that "if for every $A \in \mathcal{A}, |\mu(A)| < \infty$, then $|\mu(A)|$ is bounded by the larger of $\mu^{+}(X)$ or $\mu^{-}(X)$." The proof the textbook gives is annoyingly complicated, and I'm at a loss to see why the following doesn't suffice instead:

"We have $\mu(A) \le \mu^{+}(A) \le \mu^{+}(X)$ and $-\mu^{-}(X) \le -\mu^{-}(A) \le \mu(A)$, so that $|\mu(A)| \le \max\{\mu^{+}(X), \mu^{-}(X)\}$. Taking a Hahn decomposition we have $\mu^{+}(X) = \mu(P)$ and $\mu^{-}(X) = \mu(N)$, and if either of these were infinite then the corresponding set $P$ or $N$ would have measure $\pm \infty$, and so $|\mu(P)|$ or $|\mu(N)|$ would be $\infty$, contradicting our hypothesis about all $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Thus $\max\{\mu^{+}(X), \mu^{-}(X)\}$ will be a finite positive bound on $|\mu(A)|$."

Is there a subtlety I overlooked?